# Javascript doesn't update variables written with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that calls an AJAX, like this:

```
function addSquadronByID(id) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server/get_squadron.php",
            data: {
                'id': id,
                'counter': squadron_counter
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                squadron_counter++;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("AJAX error.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Outside the `document.ready`, the variable is initialized like this `var squadron_counter = 0;`

This function perfectly works while I call it in the page, but if I try to use PHP to write it in the page, like this:

```
        $list_squadrons = $DB->Execute($query);
        while(!$list_squadrons->EOF){
            $currentSquadron_id = $list_squadrons->fields["squadron_id"];
            $currentSquadron_number = $list_squadrons->fields["squadrons"];
            echo "addSquadronByID($currentSquadron_id);\n";
            $list_squadrons->MoveNext();
        }
```

The function writes into the document.ready() the correct calls, but `squadron_counter` is always `zero`, even if the function works. My only idea is that it works this way because javascript calls all the functions at once and does not wait to complete the first one before executing the second one, etc.. but how do I solve this?

HTML output as requested:

```
addSquadronByID(3, squadron_counter);
addSquadronByID(5, squadron_counter);
addSquadronByID(6, squadron_counter);
```

This is put into a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
});
```

inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Please show you html output. It's not clear to where the PHP script outputs.

Comment: You put the second one in the callback of the first one.

Comment: Added HTML output as requested

Comment: why just dont calculate the final value of squadron_counter in php??

Comment: When do you check for `squadron_counter` value? What do you mean by "it works while I call it in the page"? It is correct that JS will send all 3 requests without waiting for any of them to succeed (this is the expected behaviour of asynchronous tasks, as in the first "A" of AJAX). So if you check `squadron_counter` value just after having sent those 3 requests, you do not give a chance to any of those requests to complete, hence to update the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea about JS calling all functions without waiting for the first one to complete is in the right direction. This is called "asynchronous requests". Please refer to [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a detailed explanation.

The idea is to send your 3 requests and then wait for all of them to complete before checking the value of your `squadron_counter` variable (or whatever data you have updated in your `success` callbacks).

Then if my understanding is correct, you do not know how to implement this waiting?

Since you are using jQuery, the implementation is super simple. Note first that your [`jQuery.ajax` request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). So simply keep a reference of the Deferred object created by each AJAX request you send. Then you could use for example [`jQuery.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) with a callback in its `then` method to wait for all your requests to complete:

```js
function addSquadronByID(id) {
    return jQuery.ajax({ /* ... */ }); // returns a Deferred object.
}

var d1 = addSquadronByID(3),
    d2 = addSquadronByID(5),
    d3 = addSquadronByID(6);

jQuery.when(d1, d2, d3).then(
    // callback executed on success of all passed Deferred objects.
    function () {
        console.log(squadron_counter);
    }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/btjq7wuf/